# "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" in caret::train function

Tags: r, r-caret

I used R for data science, and my model trained using caret::train() function.

But here are my errors

```
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)

lassogrid <- expand.grid(
    alpha=1, lambda=seq(0.001, 0.1, by=0.0005)
)

lasso_model <- train(x=train0[,-c(which(names(train0)=="SalePrice"))], 
                y=train0$SalePrice, method = "glmnet", trControl="control", 
               tuneGrid="lassogrid")
```

then error like below:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vector

As I was searching in Google, this does not seem to be due to the train function.

But I don't know what atomic vectors actually are. So please let me know why and how to solve this problem.

Comment: And I want to know where is atomic vector in my code. Thanks

Comment: Here's traceback() results :
2.
train.default(x = as.matrix(train0[, -c(which(names(train0) == "SalePrice"))]), y = train0$SalePrice, method = "glmnet", trControl = "control", tuneGrid = "lassogrid")
1.
train(x = as.matrix(train0[, -c(which(names(train0) == "SalePrice"))]), y = train0$SalePrice, method = "glmnet", trControl = "control", tuneGrid = "lassogrid")

Comment: There are several issues, you don't need to use quotes for control, it is being interpreted as a string not variable. Other issues might be due to your method of providing the data, could you make the question more reproducible by providing data with `dput(head(train_df,n))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistakes are here `trControl="control"` and `tuneGrid="lassogrid"`. It should be `trControl=control` and `tuneGrid=lassogrid` and no need to specify the x and y. As you have not provided the data, I am using `BostonHousing` data from `mlbench` package. You can use the following code

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)

data <- BostonHousing

# create a list of 70% of the rows in the original dataset we can use for training
set.seed(123)
training <- sample(nrow(data), 0.7 * nrow(data))

train0 <- data[training,]
test0 <- data[-training,]


control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)

lassogrid <- expand.grid(
  alpha=1, lambda=seq(0.001, 0.1, by=0.0005)
)


lasso_model <- train(medv~., data= train0, method="glmnet", trControl=control, 
                     tuneGrid=lassogrid)
```

In place of `medv`, just use `SalePrice` for your data.